# Use terminal to run programs scripts a short and practice way

Tags: command-line, python, ruby, console, text-editor

in window I know make this withe the cmd but in ubuntu it's not good

I have a  question about the Terminal.
I want to ask how to call a program in the terminal

```
$ /home/yvanmoses/Dropbox/apprendre_a_programmer/"boucles en python"/mot_le_plus_frequent.py
```

the answer is permission not given.
How to put this right?
or

```
python: can't open file 'mot_le_plus_frequent.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`enter code here`
```

A second question:
Is that a short way to open a script?

My wish:
to program and verify without the "execute" button in geany (the little cogwhell in the right top)

I want to work with python and ruby

good experts saying to me to add #!/path/to/python in the first line of my script.

This work for files that are in/home/myname/
But for the files that are deep into directory into directory etc, in my Dropbox it is not good.

A priori it sames very trivial. I read many questions that someones considered as very similar to mine and find no uniform explanation.
SO I REPETE THE QUESTION WHAT is the best way for a developer (python or ruby) when he work in a script to run and run again the script easy and nicely. 
I was convicted that they use the terminal. If it is not right. I'ii accept!
WHAT TO DO???

Comment: 1.) Are you sure your path is correct?  2.) Try copy/moving and running your script from a folder not inside Dropbox.  3.) Don't use "boucles en python", but .../boucles\ en\ python/

Comment: Run the command with python, so "python /path/to/script.py". Or do chmod +x /path/to/script.py. In that case, you'll need to start the script file with #!/usr/bin/python or something like that.

Comment: @David I tried to paste the script in /home/yvanmoses/ etc but the same result.

Comment: @Jo-ErlendSchinstad yvanmoses@yvanmoses-desktop:~$ chmod +x/path/to/mot_le_plus_frequent.py
chmod: opérande manquant après «+x/path/to/mot_le_plus_frequent.py»
Saisissez « chmod --help » pour plus d'informations.
yvanmoses@yvanmoses-desktop:~$ 
It sames that It is no good. Why?

Comment: What is your first line of your file say?  The first line should be something like  #!/path/to/python  ?

Comment: Also, have you tried       python mot_le_plus_frequent.py

Comment: @David I folowed the Jo-ErlendSchinstad council: #!/usr/bin/python, but I'll try your formula

Comment: @kouty: You didn't have a space between the +x and the path. The +x means to make the file executable so that it is a program and not just a text file. So chmod +x /home/yourname/folder/mot_le_blabla.py

Comment: @kouty: But as I said, you can just run it with python, like "python /home/yourname/script.py"

Comment: @David Finally I come back. I tried to inity my script with"#!/path/to/python". I pasted a copy in the /home/m

Comment: @David Finally I come back. I tried to inity my script with"#!/path/to/python". I pasted a copy in the /home/myname/le_mot_le_plus_long2.py and it works. That is the first stape with the Terminal and I can now work with sublime text and atome. Thanks. Now I'll tried to make this independently of the directory emplacement...... HOW NO -> python: can't open file 'mot_le_plus_long.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: My error was that i tried to open a file as a directory. To open the file, after the cd path... ENTER ... python   mot_le_plus_long.py  THE RESPONSE IS THAT I CONFUSED OPEN A DIRECTORY AND OPEN A FILE